# Saving TensorFlow Neural Network KFold Cross Validation model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am working on a sample Neural Network with KFold cross validation using TensorFlow 2.4.1. and sklearn.
Unfortunately, I am not able to save the model.

```
def my_model(self,):
            inputs = keras.Input(shape=(48, 48, 3))
            x = layers.Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=self.k_size, padding='same', activation="relu")(inputs)
            x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
            x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
            x = layers.Flatten()(x)
            output = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
    
            model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    
            model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                          loss=[keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)],
                          metrics=['accuracy'])
            return model
    
def train_model(self):
    
            try:
                os.mkdir('model/saved_models')
            except OSError:
                pass
    
            try:
                os.mkdir('model/saved_graphs')
            except OSError:
                pass
    
            kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
            for train_index, test_index in kf.split(self.x_train):
                x_train, x_test = self.x_train[train_index], self.x_train[test_index]
                y_train, y_test = self.y_train[train_index], self.y_train[test_index]
                model = self.my_model()
                print(model.summary())
                trained_model = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=self.epochs, steps_per_epoch=10, verbose=2)
                trained_model = trained_model.history
                print('Model evaluation', model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose = 2))
                trained_model.save(f'model/saved_models/dummy_model_{date}')
                return trained_model
```

I am getting a following error:

```
    trained_model.save(f'model/saved_models/dummy_model_{date}')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I am not able to think of  a way to take the trained model out of the for loop. And this might be the possible reason I can think of for this problem.

Can anybody suggest how we can solve this issue? Or is there any other way to build a ANN with KFold?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yea your code has some typo:

```py
trained_model = trained_model.history # This is your train stats, so your train stats is a dictionary
model.save(f'model/saved_models/dummy_model_{date}') # This is what your saving the actual model
```

Comment: sorry, I didnt get your ans.
I tried



```python



model = self.my_model()
trained_model = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=self.epochs, steps_per_epoch=10, verbose=2)
trained_model.save(f'model/saved_models/dummy_model_{date} ' + '.h5')

```



I got this error

```

trained_model.save(f'model/saved_models/dummy_model_{date} ' + '.h5')
AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'save'

```

Comment: I also found a way to do this. by using save_weights

Comment: What i meant was that your using the variable trained_model which is just the training history, what you should be using was the model variable

Comment: aah okay! I tried that too but it did not workout. I have mentioned that in previous comments, Appoligies for the confusion and bad format of the comment.